# PowerShell script to Visual Studio application

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

Firstly I do apologise if this isn't the correct forum to be posting this question and if this isn't the place to be asking can anyone direct me to a new person forum?

Secondly you'll soon discover that I really don't know much about PowerShell or Visual Studio but I'm learning... I'm sure the Powershell script your going to see could be better but it works.

So my issue was with a system that output `.txt` files onto 2 PC's LH & RH these `.txt` files were output with different names as it was using 3 different products.

We then needed these files to be filtered by product and copied to a network drives while also being archived and deleted from the original folder.. Oh and this needed to be done real time.

So my Powershell script I've been using is the following

```
$folder = 'Target Folder'
$timeout = 1000
$filesystemwatcher = new-object system.IO.filesystemwatcher $folder
write-host "Monitoring... $folder
Transfering..."

while ($true) {
    $result = $FileSystemWatcher.WaitForChanged('all', $timeout)

    if ($result.timeout -eq $false)
    {
        write-warning ('file {0} : {1}' -f $result.changetype, $result.name)
    }

    $targetdirectory = "Target folder" 
    $sourcedirectory = "export folder" 

    if (-not(Test-Path -path $targetdirectory)) {
        New-Item $targetdirectory -Type Directory} 
        Copy-Item -Path $sourcedirectory\"*.txt" -Destination $targetdirectory 

        $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path export folder -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse

        foreach($File in $Files)
        {
            if ($File.name -like "1*.txt")
            {
                 Move-Item -Path $File.FullName "1 folder"
            }
            elseif ($File.name -like "2*.txt")
            {
                 Move-Item -Path $File.FullName "2 folder"
            }
            elseif ($File.name -like "3*.txt")
            {
                 Move-Item -Path $File.FullName "3 folder"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this script gets the files moved and works but its a Powershell script and its running 24/7 365 days a year sometimes the script had stopped sometimes the script has been messed with its just not reliable enough.

So I want to turn it into a application via Visual Studio.

Is it possible? remember i have never used Visual Studio before (Been trying it for a few hours learnt some basics)

Has anyone done anything similar to this before/ is there any guide anyone can think of that would suit my needs more?

I'm looking for the application to have the following

- A status screen ie what files it has found and where it has moved them to
- A setting option to be able to set.. amount of filter string/save paths... change source & export/archive paths etc

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Being new I don't know what to search for to get guides on my needs

Cheers

Comment: Since PowerShell is built on .NET, you can create an application in any compiled .NET language, C# being the obvious candidate.

Comment: You'll be able to use types such as `system.IO.filesystemwatcher` in C# code as well, but you'll need to find the appropriate types for replacing the PowerShell-only cmdlets such as `Copy-Item`, which you'll find in the `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: Overall, you question is not a good fit for this site - it is too broad. _Maybe_ https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com is a better place (I'm not familiar enough with it to tell).

Comment: mklement0 i do understand where your coming from my question raises so many answers i'm sure,  but what i would appreciate is just a starting point or if anyone knows of a guide that perhaps i can adapt/expand upon once i get the feel for Visual studio?  At the moment as i don't know the correct terminology for what i want to achieve i'm looking at guides that tell me how to say Hello World!

Comment: "sometimes the script had stopped sometimes the script has been messed with its just not reliable enough. So I want to turn it into a application via Visual Studio." Turning it into an application won't give you more reliability. It is more important to learn why it stopped and how it was messed up. Of course, if you are more familiar with .NET debugging than PowerShell debugging, changing to an application might make your life easier.

Comment: Lex Li its not about debugging the script being stopped is because the pc running it has been turned off and know one has started the script and some people seem to like to stop the script edit the destination folders (because of a network issue,  not a script issue). Id like the script to start when windows does along with being protected so that no one messes with it.

Comment: Also at times the script does need editing and id like that to be an easier task for people around me that don't really understand powershell scripts